# Total acceleration of 3 axis accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an Android application for measuring speed with the built-in Accelerometer. I did some low/high pass filtering to get out the gravity and the jitter, and then calculated total acceleration for one measurement like this:

```
square rot from x^2 plus y^2 plus z^2
```

The problem is that the results are always positive (of course because of taking them with the exponent 2).

But for serious calculation, I also need negative values.
For calculation of speed I use:

```
v[i] = v[i-1] + a[i-1] * t
```

I know acceleration can not be "negative", but somehow I have to define which direction (X, Y or Z) results in a positive total acceleration and which is negative.

I didn't find useful information on the internet with my research.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: You cannot measure speed with an accelerometer. You can only measure acceleration. How would you know if the device is on a stand still before the calculations? Also speed in which direction?

Comment: I assume that the device is not moving. I know that you must have the initial speed to start from which I assume is 0.0 for my case. Is there a possibility with other sensors together to get the right total acceleration using for speed calculation (with positive values if speeding up and negative values if speeding down)?

Comment: In fact values returned by the accelerometer are negative if the acceleration is happening through the negative side of the axis. Still best way to calculate speed is using GPS.

Comment: I know but GPS is not available everywhere (for example inside gym). I know that they are negative (I have negative x , y and z axis) but with my formula root(x2+y2+z2) i get just positive values so I m looking for a other solution.

Comment: Total acceleration is computed adding the three vectors together (since they are the components of the actual acceleration vector. There is no need for your formula.

Comment: If I add x and y and z together, I end up with getting random results, while using x^2 + y^2 + z^2 gives me the right curve but being just in the positive sector. Does no one know how to calculate that?

Comment: did you find a solution ? ... i have the same Q